# How to make an object pointed

Tags: objects

I am very new to blender and was wondering how to do something
I was wondering how I can kind of squish the end of an object as seen in the picture below:

[image: Picture]

**But** I want to make it so that there is a slope making a pointed object (not really, really pointed just slightly).

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on Proportional Editing (the icon in the header to the the left of the magnet), then switch over to edit mode, you can select the two vertices at the very end. Then scale them closer together and scroll your mouse wheel so that the proportional editing circle starts to pull in as much of the surrounding mesh as you desire.